# Remove/Drop duplicates EXCEPT where row contains certain string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, duplicates

I need to drop all duplicates using Pandas, except for the ones where the cell contains a certain string.

Given that DF is:

```
NAME     ID        
Joe      110
Joe      123
Joe     PENDING
Mary    PENDING
Mary     110
Justin   123
```

I need to keep rows where 'ID' is PENDING, and at the same time drop the rest of the duplicates.

Desired output looks like this:

```
NAME     ID        
Joe      110
Joe      123
Joe     PENDING
Mary    PENDING
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['Joe', 110],
        ['Joe', 123],
        ['Joe', 'PENDING'],
        ['Mary', 'PENDING'],
        ['Mary', 110],
        ['Justin', 123]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['NAME', 'ID'])

print(df[~df.duplicated('ID') | (df['ID'] == 'PENDING')])
```

As an alternative you could do:

```
print(df[df.ID.duplicated(keep='last') | df.ID.eq('PENDING')])
```

**Output**

```
   NAME       ID
0   Joe      110
1   Joe      123
2   Joe  PENDING
3  Mary  PENDING
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with inverting by `~` and chain by `|` for bitwise `OR` with compare `ID` for `PENDING` for mask for filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[~df['ID'].duplicated() | df['ID'].eq('PENDING')]
print (df)
   NAME       ID
0   Joe      110
1   Joe      123
2   Joe  PENDING
3  Mary  PENDING
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add another column in case you wanted to keep both `Name` and `ID` unique:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['Joe', 110],
        ['Joe', 123],
        ['Joe', 'PENDING'],
        ['Mary', 'PENDING'],
        ['Mary', 'PENDING'],
        ['es', 110],
        ['Joe', 110],
        ['Joe', 123]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['NAME', 'ID'])

df = df[~df.duplicated(['ID', 'NAME']) | (df['ID'] == 'PENDING')]

print(df)
```